# Typed Tagless Final Interpreters: what is the use of duplicate?

Tags: haskell, interpreter

This question is related to the paper [Typed Tagless Final Interpreters](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/lecture.pdf). In page 11, a function `trice` is presented, which relies on a `duplicate` function:

[image]

I've tried coding this into Haskell, and the resulting functions look as follows:

```
thrice :: (Int, (String, Tree)) -> IO () -- Is this the most generic type we can give?
thrice x0 = do
    x1 <- dupConsume eval x0
    x2 <- dupConsume view x1
    print $ toTree x2
    where
      dupConsume ev y = do
          print (ev y0)
          return y1
              where
                (y0, y1) = duplicate y
```

However, since I cannot seem to be able to give a more generic type to `thrice` I could have just written the simpler function:

```
thrice' :: (Int, (String, Tree)) -> IO ()
thrice' (reprInt, (reprStr, reprTree)) = do
    print $ eval reprInt
    print $ view reprStr
    print $ toTree reprTree
```

So I was wondering what is the use of `duplicate` in this example?

Comment: Please don't embed images of text. Copy the text as text.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Is there any reason why embedding an image is not convenient?

Comment: Embedded images are useless for people using screen readers or Braille displays. They're hard to read with mobile browsers. And there's no hope of searching for text within them. So just don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as an aside, note that the code in that article is already valid Haskell code, except that some symbols are used in place of usual Haskell syntax.  For example, the symbol "◦" is used in place of the `(.)` operator for function composition.

So you can write `thrice` as the following valid Haskell code, straight from its definition in the article:

```
thrice x = dup_consume eval x >>= dup_consume view 
             >>= print . toTree

dup_consume ev x = print (ev x1) >> return x2
  where (x1, x2) = duplicate x
```

Anyway, back to your question...  As you have rightly pointed out, the interpreter `duplicate` has no real purpose.  For example, you can define `dup_consume` as either the version above or else drop the `duplicate` entirely and write:

```
dup_consume ev x = print (ev x1) >> return x2
  where (x1, x2) = x
```

And, of course, you can merge the definition of `dup_consume` directly into `thrice`, as you've done.

However, *all* the final "interpreters" in the article have no real purpose.  That's kind of the point.  In particular, you don't need `eval` or `view` to define `thrice` either.  The following works fine, too:

```
thrice' :: (Int, (String, Tree)) -> IO ()
thrice' (reprInt, (reprStr, reprTree)) = do
  print $ reprInt
  print $ reprStr
  print $ reprTree
```

after which you can do the following:

```
> thrice' (add (lit 5) (neg (lit 2)))
3
"(5 + (-2))"
Node "Add" [Node "Lit" [Leaf "5"],Node "Neg" [Node "Lit" [Leaf "2"]]]
>
```

The idea with these final interpreters is that the *typing* determines the interpretation.  The purpose of the interpreters is only to add typing information without explicit type signatures.  So, `eval (neg (lit 1))` can be entered at the GHCi prompt without a type signature:

```
> eval (neg (lit 1))
-1
>
```

and it "works" because `eval` -- which is just the `id` function -- forces the return value to be an integer, which in turn selects the correct instance to *evaluate* the final expression rather than `view`ing it or something else.  But you could also write:

```
> neg (lit 1) :: Int
-1
>
```

to get the same effect.

It turns out that `duplicate` is even less necessary than the other interpreters, because in the only place where it's used -- namely the definition of `dup_consume`:

```
dup_consume ev x = print (ev x1) >> return x2
  where (x1, x2) = duplicate x
```

the type checker can already infer that a tuple is needed, so any final expression provided for `x`, like `neg (lit 1)` will necessarily be interpreted as the duplicating instance for tuples (i.e,. the instance defined right before the definition of `duplicate`), so -- as noted above -- you could just write:

```
dup_consume ev x = print (ev x1) >> return x2
  where (x1, x2) = x
```

and the type checker would figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I suspect your `thrice'` function may involve parsing the expression multiple times, whereas Oleg's `duplicate` trick will only copy the parse tree (*i.e.* parse result).

The need for duplication arises from the pattern matching on parse result, which assigns a monomorphic type to the matched parse result. Therefore, once you've chosen an interpreter for it, you're stuck with it. The paper mentions a higher-rank encoding to reclaim this lost polymorphism at the expense of extensibility, which defeats the point of tagless final interpreters.

An alternative is the `duplicate` trick which copies the (monomorphic) parse result into another (monomorphic) value to be interpreted differently.

Of course, if parsing always succeeds (for instance by encoding parse errors directly in your parse tree) then there's no need for `duplicate` since the parse result can remain polymorphic and be interpreted differently.

Comment: Also, I suspect the `duplicate` trick is also needed for languages that don't easily support  polymorphic values like Rust.